# Connecting SQL Server through Network

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have developed an App using Delphi Xe3 and SQL Server 2008. Now the app is finished and compiled. I would like to run the app on another machine that is connected to the main Machine(running SQL Server) via Wifi. However when I run the app on another machine, I get the error " Server does not exist or access denied". I have enabled the SQL server for remote access enabled TCP/IP. Someone told me I would have to be running SQL server client on the other machine to access the server database. what am I missing to be able to run my app on machine B to share the database running on machine A.

Comment: You need to find out where the actual problem lies. As a test make an ODBC connection towards your SQL server from the client. If that works, then your application should work also.

Comment: Is SQL Browser enabled on the server? Is it a default instance or named instance? Have you set a custom port? Or is it set to dynamic ports?

Comment: I could be a firewall problem serverside.. Create a new project, put an ADO connection on a form and try to connect. Thats the most simple test.

Unless you stated else you server listens on port 1433

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure what help it would be to create a new project to test this - especially when OP is asking how to connect from outside the IDE. SQL client side does not require any firewall rules - unless outgoing connections are blocked which is rare. Lucky, have you configured the firewall on the server-side to allow this port too?

Comment: Error handling! Then he knows for sure if the problem is inside his project or serverside. The advice about a new project was given because then I dont have  to explain about UDL files

Comment: @Jens That would give the exact same error message which OP already has seen, no extra error handling required. This isn't something that can be troubleshooted via debugging code. It has to do with server and network configuration.

Comment: Correct Jerry connection from an UDL fil and maing a ADO connection is the same thing.

Comment: @Lucky without giving us the info I asked about above, it's difficult to know what's going wrong. Also whoever told you that you need some sort of client software on the other machine did not know what they were talking about. Drivers, yes (which come with Windows). Client software, no.

Comment: I wonder if your problem might be your XE3 edition. I have XE2 pro, and according to the documentation client/server application development is only available in Enterprise or higher. Which version of XE3 are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I think sql server has remote connections off by default.
Run SQL Server management studio.
Right click on the server.
Properties
Connections
Under "Remote server connections", check on "Allow remote connections to this server"

Answer (score 0):

For a default SQL instance don't add the name of the instance in the connection string Data Source. It somehow works when you test the connection from udl but does not work when you use the instance name in the Delphi app.